# why do i have error for deleting Characters from NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

here in my code i am trying to load a ROBOTS.TXT file and then filter them by "Disallow" string, then if that line has "Disallow string" delete this string and return the rest of line.

here is a sample of ROBOTS.TXT

> User-agent: *
>
> Disallow:/search
>
> Disallow: /groups
>
> Disallow: /images
>
> Disallow: /catalogs
>
> Allow: /catalogs/about
>
> Disallow: /catalogues
>
> Disallow: /news
>
> Allow: /news/directory

and here is the code that i have :

```
NSRange range;
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/robots.txt"];

NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSArray *parsed = [content componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

NSMutableArray *robots=[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

NSMutableString *line= [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];


for(line in parsed){
    range=[line rangeOfString:@"Disallow"];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        [line deleteCharactersInRange: NSMakeRange(1,9 )];
        [robots addObject:line];

    }
}
```

and here is the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable
>   object with deleteCharactersInRange:'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242335/categories-for-nsmutablestring-and-nsstring-causing-binding-confusion This question may be related to yours, and may answer your question. Hope it helps

Comment: Note that `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];` can more clearly and simply be written: `[NSMutableArray array];` The convenience methods can help writing clean code and they can be used in ARC and non-ARC code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `line` in `for(line in parsed)` is immutable because an NSString is returned by the for-in statement construct.

Probably what you need:

```
for(NSString *line in parsed) {
    if [line hasPrefix:@"Disallow"]) {
        [robots addObject:[line substringFromIndex:9];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet returns an NSArray of NSString. NSString is immutable. You are declaring line as an NSMutableString, but the object that gets assigned to line is still an NSString.